# PHP stmt_bind_assoc() function reference

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, reference, prepared-statement

Same question as this guy 7 years ago: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#83073

This function takes metadata from a prepared SQL query, `$stmt`, then allows you to retrieve multiple rows with many columns through the array provided in `$out`.

```
function stmt_bind_assoc(&$stmt, &$out) {
    $data = mysqli_stmt_result_metadata($stmt);
    $fields = array();
    $out = array();

    $fields[0] = $stmt;
    $count = 1;

    while($field = mysqli_fetch_field($data)) {
        $fields[$count] = &$out[$field->name];
        $count++;
    }   
    call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_result', $fields);
}
```

From here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#82742

Used like such:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name FROM user WHERE user_id=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $userid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    $rowdata = array(); //Create array to hold all data in returned row
    stmt_bind_assoc($stmt, $rowdata); //Get all values in row

    while ($stmt->fetch()) { //Store all events data
        $returnedData = new someRandomObject($rowdata['user_id'], $rowdata['user_name']);
    }
}
```

Each time the while loop is looped through, the `$rowdata` array will update with the next row's column values.

The problem is when I try to store the `$rowdata` array's keys and values in another array.

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) { //Store all events data
    $arrayOfAllRows[] = $rowdata;
}
```

Because of the references in `stmt_bind_assoc`, the `$arrayOfAllRows`, after the while loop executes, will just contain a bunch of references to the last `$rowdata` array that was generated, so instead of having 10 different rows, you get 10 copies of the same row.

---

My question is: How do the references work in `stmt_bind_assoc`, and how can I make it so that the entire `$rowdata` array is copied to the `$arrayOfAllRows`?

Comment: You can try `$arrayOfAllRows[] =  clone $rowdata`, but I think thats already implicit. Afaik the only data type that is not implicitly copied when assigned to another variable are objects.

Comment: Yeah I thought that arrays were always copied by value, but I guess I'm misunderstanding something here...

Comment: Oh, I see. `mysqli_fetch_field` returns an object. Even though the array itself is copied by value, the objects its storing are not.

Comment: Try `clone` anyway, if it doesn't work use `unserialize(serialize($rowdata))` to force cloning of the array and its elements.

Comment: Or what you're actually looking for is `->fetch_all()`.

Comment: Any particular reason to use this method? You can use `$result = $stmt->get_result()` instead and then iterate with `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())`, no need for any of this `stmt_bind_assoc` thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $stmt->execute();
$rows = array();
stmt_bind_assoc($stmt, $row);
while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
    $rows[] = array_copy($row);
    }

break;
}

function array_copy(array $array)
{
$result = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val)
    {
    if (is_array($val))
        {
        $result[$key] = arrayCopy($val);
        }
    elseif (is_object($val))
        {
        $result[$key] = clone $val;
        }
      else
        {
        $result[$key] = $val;
        }
    }

return $result;
}
```